# Xcode 7.3 archiving ends but crashes Xcode with error : bundleIdentifier should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

An enterprise app written in swift and having dependencies on libraries and frameworks(swift or objc) archives successfully and gives ipa successfully when archived using Xcode 7.2.1 but on Xcode 7.3 the archiving succeeds but crashes without giving an ipa with following error message,

```
    Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

    Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
    Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

    Application Specific Information:
    ProductBuildVersion: 7D175
    ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-10183.3/IDEProducts/DVTProducts/DVTProducts/DVTProducts/DVTProductVersion.m:44
    Details:  bundleIdentifier should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
    Object:   <DVTProductVersion: 0x7ff47b18ac40>
    Method:   -initWithBundleIdentifier:version:buildNumber:name:childProducts:productCategory:
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff471c18210>{number = 1, name = main}
    Hints:   None
    Backtrace:
      0   -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
      1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
      3   -[DVTProductVersion initWithBundleIdentifier:version:buildNumber:name:childProducts:productCategory:] (in DVTProducts)
      4   +[DVTProductVersion productVersionFromArchive:withError:] (in DVTProducts)
      5   -[DVTArchiveProductSource _productsFromArchives:coordinator:] (in DVTProducts)
      6   __58-[DVTArchiveProductSource updateArchivesDelayedInvocation]_block_invoke (in DVTProducts)
      7   -[DVTDelayedInvocation runBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
      8   -[DVTDelayedInvocation invokeIfNeeded] (in DVTFoundation)
      9   -[DVTArchiveProductSource refreshProducts] (in DVTProducts)
     10   +[IDEArchivesViewController revealArchive:] (in IDEProductsUI)
     11   +[IDEArchivesViewController revealArchiveNotification:] (in IDEProductsUI)
     12   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation)
     13   ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
     14   _CFXRegistrationPost (in CoreFoundation)
     15   ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
     16   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] (in CoreFoundation)
     17   _CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation)
     18   -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation)
     19   -[NSNotificationCenter(DVTNSNotificationCenterAdditions) _dvt_postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in DVTFoundation)
     20   __42-[IDEArchiveManager _revealArchiveAtPath:]_block_invoke (in IDEFoundation)
     21   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
     22   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
     23   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
     24   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
     25   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
     26   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
     27   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
     28   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
     29   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
     30   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
     31   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
     32   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
     33   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
     34  0x000000010028b39b (in Xcode)
     35   start (in libdyld.dylib)


abort() called
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you sure your project has a valid bundle identifier? If yes, then you should log that bug on Apple support site. It looks like a bug on their end.

Comment: I have logged a bug lets wait.

Comment: This bug was resolved in Xcode 7.3.1 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was given to this bug by apple(as copy pasted below), and was fixed in Xcode 7.3.1

> Hi rgh,
>
> This is a courtesy email regarding Bug ID# 25849118.
>
> Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue:
>
> You can workaround this issue by following these steps:
>
> 1. Close Xcode.
> 2. Move ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Products to a different location.
> 3. Reopen Xcode. Attempt rearchiving.
>
> You should then be able to put back your product directory. If the
>   crash still occurs, please let us know.
>
> THE INFORMATION CONTAINED IN THIS MESSAGE IS UNDER NON-DISCLOSURE
>
> Bug ID #: 25849118 Bug Title: Xcode 7.3 succeeds archiving but crashes
>   before creation of ipa
>
> Summary: Currently archiving with Xcode
>   7.2.1 without any issues. As the log suggests i have gone through all libraries, bundles and frameworks which are included as dependencies
>   if any of has missed setting bundle identifier. After confirming
>   nothing is missing it still crashes with the same issue.
>
> Steps to Reproduce:
>   1. Start archiving.
>   2. After build succeeds and just before creation of ipa, crash.
>
> Expected Results: IPA
>
> Actual Results: Crash
>
> Version: Xcode 7.3 OSX El Capitan 10.11.4 (15E65)
>
> Notes: Tried deleting all derived data. Did try after setting missing
>   bundle identifier for all included dependencies(frameworks, bundles,
>   libraries).
>
> Configuration: xcode 7.2.1 on the same machine succeeds.
>
> Attachments: 'Xcode_2016-04-19-140323_Raghavendras-MacBook-Pro.crash'
>   was successfully uploaded.